# Why am I getting a rate limiting error on post requests?

Tags: node.js, express, sentry

Whenever I send a post request, I'm getting the following error. I couldn't track down where it is coming from.

```
SentryError: HTTP Error (429): Creation of this event was denied due to rate limiting
    at new SentryError (/home/bwsuser/bws-verwaltung/node_modules/@sentry/core/dist/error.js:9:28)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/bwsuser/bws-verwaltung/node_modules/@sentry/node/dist/transports/base.js:46:44)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:543:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:112:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

anyone has any idea what might be causing that? or at least where to start looking.
I ran out of ideas here :/

Comment: Looks like whatever API you're calling has decided you called it too many times.

Comment: Try tomorrow... Could you share what service you are requesting?

Comment: The post request is going to the backend. there is a limiter set up there but only on the get requests.

Answer (score 0):

> **anyone has any idea what might be causing that? or at least where to start looking. I ran out of ideas here :/**

Yes, certainly, you need to look here at [Quota Management | Sentry Documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/quotas/#what-counts-toward-my-quota-an-overview.). It mostly happens when you run an app from a local dev server. Here's the summary right from the doc ...

> Sentry completes a thorough evaluation of each event to determine if it counts toward your quota, as outlined in this overview. Detailed documentation for each evaluation is linked throughout. Before completing any of these evaluations, Sentry confirms that each event includes a valid DSN and project as well as whether the event can be parsed. In addition, for error events, Sentry validates that the event contains valid fingerprint information. If any of these items are missing or incorrect, the event is rejected.

Another hint, try to disable all your browser extensions and check if that call is gone. I just figure out it is called by a chrome extension for me.

Hope helps